# forest node with two rows of trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest

I want to create tree where a node itself can have multiple trees.It should look something like this:

[image: Goal Tree]

What I have tried so far:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{forest}
label tree,
[A
  [{B
   [C][D]}
   {E
   [F][G]},
   align=center
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{center}
```

[image: First Try]

```
\begin{center}
\begin{forest}
label tree,
[A
  [B
   [C][D]
   E
   [F][G],
   align=center
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{center}
```

[image: Second Try]

My Question is the goal tree even possible with the forest package since it is strictly speaking not a tree, or does anybody know how to create such a tree with another package like tikz-tree?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're looking for, but as you say, multidominance structures aren't trees. See [Multi-rooted Tree-like Structures and Nodes with Multiple Parents in LaTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/114109),  [How to connect two parents to the same child, with parents not in the same tree?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/146183), and [How to get limited multidominance in a forest tree](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/451026) for some ideas on how best to do this.

Comment: I want basically a sort of group node in which itself is another tree. So that in my example there is an edge from A to the group (E,F,G) and from this group to group (B,C,D)

Comment: If A dominates E, F, G, as three nodes, what do you want the dominance relation between those nodes and the nodes B, C, D? Should they dominate a node that then dominates B, C, D? I.e., to make this even a proper graph (though not a tree) there must be *some*  relation between the nodes, they can't be disjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Between nodes F and G is inserted empty nde with options `coordinate` and `no edge` which child is node B with childs C and D:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {inner sep=2pt,
            s sep=3mm,
            l sep=2mm
            }
[A
    [E
        [F]
        [,coordinate, no edge
            [B
                [C]
                [D]
            ]
        ]
        [G]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```